# why don't I have the same response with curl than my browser?

Tags: curl, browser, request

Hi I'm trying to automatically request a room on the website https://www.watchparty.me/

so I make a request at https://www.watchparty.me/createRoom which is the endpoint to get a new room.

when I use it with a common browser I get a response like this:
[image: how my browser answers the request]

while when I try to do the same with `curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0" -L "watchparty.me/createRoom"`

I get this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
      <meta name="description" content="Watch together with friends. Chat and react in real time to the same stream, whether it's YouTube, your own video, or a virtual browser."/>
      <meta property="og:image" content="/screenshot4.png"/>
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/favicon.png"/>
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
      <title>WatchParty</title>
      <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.e4f3a69c.js"></script>
      <link href="/static/css/main.9154545e.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>!function(){var a="fbclid";if(-1!==location.search.indexOf("fbclid=")){var e="";try{var c=new URL(location);c.searchParams.delete(a),e=c.href}catch(a){var l=new RegExp("[?&]fbclid=.*$");e=location.search.replace(l,""),e=location.pathname+e+location.hash}history.replaceState(null,"",e)}}()</script>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
   </body>
   <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-45337794-6"></script><script>function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments)}window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[],gtag("js",new Date),gtag("config","UA-45337794-6")</script>
</html>
```

Does anyone knows why I get such different responses and how I could get the same as on my browser ?

Comment: in a word: javascript

Comment: If you try to disable JS in your browser then refresh: no content at all. You need a JS aware lib, like Selenium, https://pptr.dev, Playwright...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first screenshot you shared, you can see the column "Initiator", and you can notice that the `POST` request got sent from Javascript.

In the second screenshot, you have this message "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app" in the `<noscript>` HTML tag (that displays in a browser when Javascript is disabled).

When you are doing the request with your browser, the Javascript is interpreted. When you use curl, no Javascript is involved, and then it does not send the API request you are looking for.